# Macro does not execute completely when using python

Tags: python, excel, vba

When I run macro in Excel, the code executes completely. But the code is not completely done when I try to run macro using Python.

In the VBA code, I used this code to ignore all error triangles in each cell so the file created did not include these errors(image below).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DMnY.png)

But when I try to use macro in Python. The triangle errors occur, and I don't know why (Python code).

import os
import win32com.client as wincl

def runMacro(file_path):
if os.path.exists(file_path):
excel_macro = wincl.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")

```
    workbook = excel_macro.Workbooks.Open(file_path)#,None,False)

    try:
            excel_macro.Application.Run("module1.create_WP")
            workbook.Save()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        excel_macro.Application.Quit()
        del excel_macro
```

path = "D:\OneDrive - Central Group\Khôi\Weekly performance\Original files\TOTAL2022(UPDT.).xlsm"
runMacro(path).

The triangle errors occur [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3f0j.png)

Comment: Don't post code as image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it this way and feed back results?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import unittest
import os.path
import win32com.client

class ExcelMacro(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_excel_macro(self):
        try:
            xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
            xlsPath = os.path.expanduser('C:\\Excel.xlsb')
            wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=xlsPath)
            xlApp.Run('Macro1')
            wb.Save()
            xlApp.Quit()
            print("Macro ran successfully!")
        except:
            print("Error found while running the excel macro!")
            xlApp.Quit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Your codes run successfully, thank you so much.

Comment: But I have a question: Could excel can ignore the errors triangle by VBA, I try a lot of codes and it just ignores these errors one time. When I close and reopen the file, the codes occur. I must ignore these errors by hand because my boss want them disappear, and it waste to much time.

Comment: On Error Resume Next

Also, if you get a lot of Ctrl+Break stops, reboot your machine. That should fix that issue. Ctrl+Breaks build up over time if you halt the running of your code a lot.